# MAMP PHP Extension intl failure In Magento Setup

Tags: php, mamp

Trying to install Magento 2.2 locally on my Windows computer with MAMP. Received an error that the following PHP extensions were missing:

PHP Extension xsl and
PHP Extension intl

I went into the appropriate php.ini file for my version of PHP and removed the ; from infront of ;extension=php_xsl.dll and ;extension=php_intl.dll and restarted the server. The xsl.dll file works, but the intl.dll file is still missing.

I have checked and the extensions appear in the correctly in the file structure. Scratching my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSHed and installed the correct extensions from the Sury PHP 7.2 library to my localhost